# Merging another dataframe to existing rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes `df` and `subs` as:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"scode": [11, 22, 33, 44], "sname": ["aa", "bb", "cc", "dd"], "sub1": [ "London", np.nan, "Delhi", np.nan], "sub2": [np.nan, np.nan, "Sydney", np.nan]})

   scode sname  sub1    sub2
0   11   aa     London  NaN
1   22   bb     NaN     NaN
2   33   cc     Delhi   Sydney
3   44   dd     NaN     NaN

subs = {0: [22, 44], 1: ["Milford Sound", "Queenstown"], 2: ["Oslo", np.nan]}

    0   1               2
0   22  Milford Sound   Oslo
1   44  Queenstown      NaN
```

How to merge the 2 dataframes and end up with the result as:

```
    scode   sname   sub1            sub2
0   11      aa      London          NaN
1   22      bb      Milford Sound   Oslo
2   33      cc      Delhi           Sydney
3   44      dd      Queenstown      NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas will automatically align on indices/columns, just make sure you set the correct index, assuming `scode` is how you want to merge things:

```
In [5]: df = pd.DataFrame({"scode": [11, 22, 33, 44], "sname": ["aa", "bb", "cc", "dd"], "sub1": [ "London", np.nan, "Delhi", np.nan], "sub2": [np.nan, np.nan, "Sydne
    ...: y", np.nan]})
    ...:

In [6]: df.set_index('scode',inplace=True)

In [7]: subs = pd.DataFrame({0: [22, 44], 1: ["Milford Sound", "Queenstown"], 2: ["Oslo", np.nan]})
    ...:

In [8]: subs.set_index(0, inplace=True)

In [9]: subs.columns=['sub1','sub2']
```

Giving you something like:

```
In [10]: df
Out[10]:
      sname    sub1    sub2
scode
11       aa  London     NaN
22       bb     NaN     NaN
33       cc   Delhi  Sydney
44       dd     NaN     NaN

In [11]: subs
Out[11]:
             sub1  sub2
0
22  Milford Sound  Oslo
44     Queenstown   NaN
```

Now, just do normal assignment, selecting the appropriate columns/index:

```
In [12]: df.loc[subs.index.values,['sub1', 'sub2']] = subs

In [13]: df
Out[13]:
      sname           sub1    sub2
scode
11       aa         London     NaN
22       bb  Milford Sound    Oslo
33       cc          Delhi  Sydney
44       dd     Queenstown     NaN
```

You can always reset the index you were using before:

```
In [14]: df.reset_index(inplace=True)

In [15]: df
Out[15]:
   scode sname           sub1    sub2
0     11    aa         London     NaN
1     22    bb  Milford Sound    Oslo
2     33    cc          Delhi  Sydney
3     44    dd     Queenstown     NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

First, let's get your column names to match:

```
newSub = sub.rename(columns={0:'scode', 1:'sub1', 2:'sub2'})
```

Next, the `update` method of the dataframe does what you want based on common index between the source and destination rows.  So, let's set the index to scode:

```
indexedDF     = df.set_index('scode')
indexedNewSub = newSub.set_index('scode')
```

Finally, use `indexedDF`'s updated method to update in place:

```
indexedDF.update(indexedNewSub)
```

`indexedDF` should now have `subs` merged in as requested.